# Excel spreadsheet like library in Swing (=improved JTable)

Tags: java, swing, spreadsheet

I'm searching for a free, open-source if possible, Java swing library that improves the existent JTable (which is very simple).

I want to do an application with a spreadsheet similar to Excel one. Without the formula but with copy/paste functionalities (multiple paste if multiple selection), column reorganizing, etc...

I've found some, like JGrid (Jeppers) but is to simple. Or KTable, NatTable, NebulaGrid but they are for SWT :(. QuickTable seems cool but the free version has an advertisement text display above the grid...

Comment: +1 for mentioning the other libraries !! thanks

Comment: I'm looking for this too: Keyboard navigation, F2 to edit. etc, is a winner concept for any application with more than a few text fields. It would be nice to know if the keyboard navigation is working in the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any free solutions that suite your needs. [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) offers JXTable, which I assume is too simple for you. Haven't tried it myself, though. [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/) does have some powerful table components but they're not free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Khilon. But yes, JXTable seems to simple, and I can't pay to acquire JIDE :(

Comment: After returning on their site it appeared that JIDE can offers their product from whom developed open source project...I'm in this case (I hadn't precising it) so I will contact them to see if it was possible.
Many thanks Khilon :)

Answer (score 1):

There is another spreadsheet component named [Jxcell](http://www.jxcell.net) is really good(not free).

Comment: anyone have experience with this? I am considering purchasing this one.

Comment: From a quick look, Jxcell seems more geared towards working with files written in the Excel document format, rather than adding Excel-like editing capabilities to tables.

Comment: The unlimited license costs $999.00: http://www.jxcell.net/purchase.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [OpenJFX/JavaFX JFXPanel](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) to put an [OpenJFX/JavaFX spreadsheet view](https://controlsfx.github.io/features/spreadsheetview/) (from ControlsFX, under the permissive BSD-3-Clause license) into a Swing application.

I've found no actively maintained free of charge solution purely implemented in Swing.

Answer (score 0):

I've written [Joeffice](https://www.joeffice.com), an open source (Apache license) office suite in Swing that includes viewing and editing Excel spreadsheet. The new version is coming in one month or 2. See also my post 2 days ago about [Excel Viewer for IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.japplis.com/news/2023/04/17/an-excel-viewer-for-intellij-idea/).