# Do you know of a sophisticated spread sheet like component for Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, spreadsheet

I need to write a data exploration tool that displays large amounts of data in a spreadsheet format.

Salient problem features:

1. Large number of rows -- typically .5 to 1 million
2. 30-50 columns
3. Need to be able to sort on columns
4. Rapidly apply filters -- say hide all rows that have have foobar in them
5. Need to be able to lock rows/cols

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the libraries suggested at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058264/excel-spreadsheet-like-library-in-swing-improved-jtable?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a component.  However, it is relatively easy to add sorting and filtering using a standard `JTable`.  I'm not sure what you mean by locking rows / columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is elucidating the poorly defined row count requirement: *typically 0.5 to 1 million*. Human beings cannot meaningfully browse hundreds of thousand of rows. Instead, consider some domain-compatible way to select a subset suitable for manipulation according to the other requirements 2-5.

Because its [renderers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) implement the flyweight pattern, [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) is already quite efficient, although [optimizations](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/ChristmasTree/) are possible. If the data is hierarchical in nature, [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html), a `JTable` subclass examined [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4447#4447), is an appealing alternative.

Comment: +1 `typically 0.5 to 1 million` without Paginations is for me nonsence