# Does the forms still in the memory as long as the application runs?

Tags: java, swing, memory

I am developing a swing application concerning university management system and schedule generation (using java swing) as the figure below:

[image: University Management System Form]

The user have to reserve a room for a given course 
 (this is done by selecting a course in the JTable and by clicking the **Reserve** button
The process of rooms reservation is done using a JOptionPane which loads all the rooms and put them as a matrix of JButton on the JFrame and this JFrame is cloned on the JOptionPane window like this figure below :

[image: The red buttons means that theses room is reserved in this time slot]

According to the high number of rooms and the number of time slot in each day, this reservation window take about 10 - 15 seconds to load all theses rooms, 
Then after reserving a room, the window closes or the user can close the window without reserving by clicking the "OK" button 

**But when i reopen this same window, it takes about 3-4 seconds only !**
  
  **And this is when i close the connection to database after getting the data (the rooms names) , and after closing the window ! (JOptionPane)**  
 

My question is : **what is the reason ?** 

If I close the cnx and the window, why the second time i open this window ( **as long as the application runs in the same session**), it takes less time?

It seems that this window still in the memory of the pc or something else?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably down to cache either on your local pc or on the db and/or both.

Comment: Consider `JTable` for the reservation view to leverage [flyweight rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7665982/230513).

Comment: I just wanted to say your application looks really professional good stuff.

Comment: Sorry thought I did. There you go!

Comment: I doubt the window rendering is the one which is taking different times. I suspect the DB connection. What are you using for DB connection? Does the connection has a hostname part that is resolved the first time and subsequently cached?

Comment: Closing Swing window/jframe visually not always means destroying, it depends on code