# How to create a webpage similar to Google's online spreadsheet?

Tags: java, open-source, spreadsheet

I need to create a webpage quite similar to Google's great Docs spreadsheet, but in my case I cannot use their's.
Also there is no need to have the full feature set of the Google Docs spreadsheet (which is really big!).
But my minimal feature set is:
- change, add, delete cells and content
- change of formats like color, size, font
- the functions sum(), avg(), count()
My preferred tools are JSP, tomcat, JQuery. The server representation does not matter and could be any of xml, text, database tables or s.th. else.

I am quite sure, that there are perfect open solutions out there - which I can use to start - to fit my requirements but my problem is to **find** them. 
Searching for "Google spreadsheet alternative" did not work very well.
Any hint or link is appreciated.
Thank you.
Alex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058264/excel-spreadsheet-like-library-in-swing-improved-jtable

Comment: @AramKocharyan: The question involved an online solution, not a swing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [primefaces sheet](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/sheet.jsf).  If you like jQuery and use JSP, you should consider learning JSF and use primefaces since primefaces already heavily uses jQuery, meaning if you have to personalize the behavior of its controls, you are already presented with a familiar interface.

Primefaces sheet seems to provide what you're looking for, which is to say, something similar to an excel sheet.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be very easy - but now I stick in some traps around JSF.

Comment: @Alex004, though a bit of advice to a jsper turning to jsf for the first time.  It's tempting to use a lot of javascript.  I encourage you to try to understand how to do it in jsf first, since most of the time it's not a matter of **if** jsf can do something but how.

Comment: Neil, thank you. Could you help me please a little bit to get a stupid JSF example running? I stuck totally in the mess of Java versions. I could not find one single tutorial which matches to the currently available versions of Tomcat, JSF, JSTL. Here is what I use: tomcat 6.0.35, JSF: mojarra-1.2_15-b01-FCS-binary.zip, JSTL: 1.1.2

Comment: @Alex004.  Unfortunately, I use primefaces 3.2, which requires jsf 2.0, so I can't help you much in that respect.  Though at least I can give you [this link](http://jsfprimefacesblog.blogspot.it/2010/08/setup-prime-faces-in-tomcat-60-or.html) which at least can tell you how to get it to work with tomcat 6 and which versions to use.  Alternatively you can try [here](http://open-garage.blogspot.it/2010/09/getting-started-with-prime-faces-2.html) if you use Maven.  Hope that helps.